# Trying to get a Camel sample using CXF working on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to get an apache camel app using CXF working on WebSphere.

Noticed a number of errors

Caused by: java.lang.**IncompatibleClassChangeError**: org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)

This occurs because the org.apache.neethi classes are loaded from the WAS run-time instead of the neeti3.0.2.jar  from WEB-INF/lib

here is the info from class loader:

class load: org.apache.neethi.builders.AssertionBuilder from: file:**/D:/Tools/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/org.apache.axis2.jar**

The Web Application config has been changed to use the class loader policy. It is set to Parent Last. *Yet this class seems to be using the Parent First Policy.*

Is there anything in the CXF package that over-rides this policy?

I noticed that using Axis2 and WAS

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

Avoiding conflicts with WebSphere's JAX-WS runtime has some additional steps mentioned for Axis2. Is there something similar that is required to get this to work?

Thanks
Manglu

Answer (score 3):

Not specific to Camel, but we are dealing with a similar issue.

1) You can use an isolated shared library if you want. This seems to fix the classloader from pulling in these other libraries via OSGi. This solution isn't for everyone.

2) When setting an app that PARENT_LAST, make sure you're doing it in the correct place. If you have jars inside your wars, then you'll have to set PARENT_LAST on the **WAR modules**, not the application. In the WAS console> Applications > Application Type > websphere enterprise applications> MyEAR > manage Modules > MyWar > Change the "Class loader order" and make it "parent last"

3) After you make your changes, you can export the ear file. In the ear, there is a file META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp/deployment.xml that has this config. For maven ear's, you can put this into src/main/application for it to be packaged up with the ear.

Hope that this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

We are discussing a similar topic at the Camel mailing lists. I suggest to take a look there: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-cxf-in-WebSphere-without-geronimo-jetty-depdendencies-possible-tp5726490.html

Comment: Hi Claus, Interestingly moving all the JARs under WEB-INF/lib to a shared library eliminates this issue. I still don't see a reason why but it does look like a class loader hierarchy quirk somewhere here. I will investigate further and post back the findings/observations.